# How do I get notified when an array property changes?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, properties, inotifypropertychanged

My class contain many properties and i need to handle each properties.

See this below:

```
public partial class my_form : Form
{
    private Image[] _imagelist;
    public Image[] imagelist
    {
        get
        {
            return _imagelist;
        }
        set
        {
            this._imagelist = value;
            this.on_imagelist_changed();
        }
    }

    private void on_imagelist_changed()
    {
        // do something.
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* set new imagelist */
        this.imagelist = getimagelist();
    }
}
```

Yes, It's work fine.

But when i call like this.

```
public partial class my_form
{
    private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].ImageIndex;
        this.imagelist[selectedIndex] = dosomething(this.imagelist[selectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

It's don't call `on_imagelist_changed()`. Why ?

I can't add property by indexer like this. :(

```cs
public partial class my_form
{
    public Image imagelist[int x]
    {
        get
        {
            return _imagelist[x];
        }
        set
        {
            this._imagelist[x] = value;
            this.on_imagelist_changed();
        }            
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Can i avoid to make a control class like this [C# Indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) ?

I founded some suggestion, they told me let try [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). I don't understand about this. May be someone example for me ?

Comment: Just use lists instead of arrays ( private List<Image> _imagelist;
        public static List<Image> imagelist). The reason you cant do this.imagelist[selectedIndex] = dosomething(this.imagelist[selectedIndex]); is because the array has not been initialized, (thats why I recommend using a list instead, all you have to do is imagelist = new List<Image>(); to initialize it)

Comment: @Innat3 The array has been initialized, otherwise the code would crash. The error is not a crash, though, but the fact that the event is not "firing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's don't call `on_imagelist_changed()`. Why?

Because, quite bluntly, `imageList` has not changed. Some images inside `imageList` may have changed, but your code reacts only to the change of the entire `imageList`. The assignment calls `get` of your property twice; it never calls the setter.

> I can't add property by indexer like this.

That's correct. However, you correctly noted that you could use an observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Image> Images {get;}

private void OnImageListChanged(
    object sender
,   NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // do something.
}

public MyForm() {
    Images = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
    Images.CollectionChanged += OnImageListChanged;
}
```

Comment: collectionchanged doesn't fire when item is being updated so note you have to remove or add items to make it work.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary According to the documentation, the event "occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed." This includes the assignment of an item back to the list, the way the OP shows (i.e. `this.Images[selectedIndex] = dosomething(this.Images[selectedIndex]);`) The event wouldn't fire if OP modifies the item without reassigning, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank !

Answer (score 0):

Because your property gets and sets **pointer** to array, not array itself. So when you change array items pointer stays the same.

That's why [properties should not return arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1819?view=vs-2019).